# angular + require.js :Failed to instantiate module

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

My code :
**index.html**

```
<html ng-app='Arrows'>
 <script data-main="main" src="require.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="My">
  {{status}}
</div>
```

And main.js file

```
    require(["jquery","underscore","backbone",
"marionette","angular"], function($ ,_,Backbone,Marionette,angular){

      debugger

       var app = angular.module("Arrows")
      angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['Arrows']);
        });  

      app.controller('My', function($scope) {
            $scope.status = 'hello! Its working!';
        });
    })
```

I have problem :

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   Arrows due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'Arrows' is not
>   available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
>   If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as
>   the second argument.

Answer (score 8):

Remove the ng-app directive from your html. You already manually bootstrap it.

```
<script data-main="main" src="require.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="My">
  {{status}}
</div>
```

That has to be enough for code.

By the way I would not use Backbone and Angular in a same app.

Comment: I get error: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'My' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: Can you prepare a jsfiddle or plunker as a playground? Thus we can edit and see what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You must instantiate the module

```
angular.module('name', [])  // this will instantiate the module

angular.module('name')      // this will not instantiate the module and give you 
                            // an error if the previous line has not been called first. 
                            // This function can be used to add controllers, services 
                            // etc. to the module, for example in another file.
```

Comment: I added angular.module("Arrows",[]) but the same result  ....Help me please.....please

Comment: I get it working when adding angular.module("Arrows", []). http://plnkr.co/edit/ysdNKDXcHB1BBgXwQcIf?p=preview Maybe you problem is using require, backbone etc. Do you really need these frameworks when using Angular?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, this is a problem of loading sequence, I may be mistaken but according to what I've experienced:

- the html files are loading first
- requireJs file is executed

Then, the problem is that each time you use an angular directive, it is resolved **before** the actual module/controller/etc. is loaded.

The trick of bootstraping the app to the document works, but in order to have a fully fonctional application, you need to **bootstrap everything manually** and not using the "ng-controller" (and other directives).

For me, this is not a solution, just a workaround and I'm sure requireJs can (or should) do better, so either it's a requireJs' bug or there is another solution.

Hope this helps!